# Troubleshooting slow UPDATE query

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have an UPDATE query of the form

```
UPDATE table SET ... WHERE id = ?
```

where `id` is the primary key.  Also, the table has InnoDB as engine.  I would expect this query to be as slow as the disk write that it entails.  Sometimes though, it takes much more, up to a few seconds.

Is it correct to conclude, at least to a good degree of probability, that there must be another query, equally slow, locking the whole `table` or the row to be updated?  If I'm mistaken, what other possible causes are there and how to properly investigate the issue?

Answer (score 2):

INNODB locks index regions, and sometimes the INSERT and UPDATE queries contend for the same index region. This might be what's happening. You can read more about troubleshooting INNODB locking issues [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-standard-monitor.html).

Comment: +1, but do you think this is due to a deadlock then? SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS doesn't show the most recent deadlock, so I assume there was none, actually. Am I wrong?

Comment: If it were a true deadlock, this query (or the other one) would have been aborted and `ROLLedBACK`.  Look for other competing queries.